# Texto com contraste de cor em relação ao background utilizando chroma.js

Tags: javascript, css, css3

No seguinte arquivo [Gerador de temas aleatorios](https://jsfiddle.net/a41gmfmo/) tenho o código que utiliza o chroma.js para verificar a cor do bg fazendo o texto ter contraste, porém ele só gera uma cor para cada cor de fundo e gostaria que ele gerasse mais de uma cor como posso fazer?

Comment: O código está gerando sim uma cor de fundo a cada click. Deve melhorar sua pergunta.